# How to format current time using a yyyyMMddHHmmss format?

Tags: time, go, format, timestamp

I'm trying to format the current time using this format `yyyyMMddHHmmss`.

```
t := time.Now()
fmt.Println(t.Format("yyyyMMddHHmmss"))
```

That is outputting:

```
yyyyMMddHHmmss
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Here's a playground sample of how date formatting works. This is both converting string to time and print out a time in a specific format. https://play.golang.org/p/qK6_9KNJNx

Answer (score 402, accepted):

Use

```
fmt.Println(t.Format("20060102150405"))
```

as Go uses following constants to format date,refer [here](http://golang.org/src/pkg/time/format.go)

```
const (
    stdLongMonth      = "January"
    stdMonth          = "Jan"
    stdNumMonth       = "1"
    stdZeroMonth      = "01"
    stdLongWeekDay    = "Monday"
    stdWeekDay        = "Mon"
    stdDay            = "2"
    stdUnderDay       = "_2"
    stdZeroDay        = "02"
    stdHour           = "15"
    stdHour12         = "3"
    stdZeroHour12     = "03"
    stdMinute         = "4"
    stdZeroMinute     = "04"
    stdSecond         = "5"
    stdZeroSecond     = "05"
    stdLongYear       = "2006"
    stdYear           = "06"
    stdPM             = "PM"
    stdpm             = "pm"
    stdTZ             = "MST"
    stdISO8601TZ      = "Z0700"  // prints Z for UTC
    stdISO8601ColonTZ = "Z07:00" // prints Z for UTC
    stdNumTZ          = "-0700"  // always numeric
    stdNumShortTZ     = "-07"    // always numeric
    stdNumColonTZ     = "-07:00" // always numeric
    stdFracSecond0    = ".0", ".00" // trailing zeros included
    stdFracSecond9    = ".9", ".99" // trailing zeros omitted
)
```

Comment: is it possible to use stdLongYear or stdNumMonth instead of 2006 or 1?

Comment: acturally the golang format is very strange. why not use the yyyymmddHHiiss  style ,  but use the ""2006/01/02/15/04/05", I have   not get it the real reason

Comment: The layout string is a representation of the time stamp, Jan 2 15:04:05 2006 MST. 

An easy way to remember this value is that it holds, when presented in this order, the values (lined up with the elements above):

1 2  3  4  5    6  -7

From https://golang.org/src/time/example_test.go

Comment: Mnemonic technique for those outside the US: figure what you were doing on the 2nd of January of 2006, just five seconds after 15:04, but imagine it happenning in Burkina Faso (UTC -7). Next time you need to format a date, just remember this particular event (!)

Comment: am I missing something or there is no way to format with sub-second precision?

Comment: @aiguy - go does support sub-second precision precision by using `.9`, `.99`, ... `.999999`, etc.

Comment: I did not know the sequential mnemonic, handy, but come on why is it not the 1st February...

Comment: So all I have to remember, is to line up the date in month-day-year order, then stick the time in the middle of it, and put the timezone after the year, and it becomes super easy to remember. Neat.

Anyone got a mnemonic for remembering the order of this mnemonic..?

Comment: @Kewin Agree with you. I am even pissed off by it. The "YYMMDD..." way is perfectly understandable and easy to remember. Look, what the hell is that ---"20060102150405"? What the hell are they thinking?

Comment: Time to write a proper Time function that isn't linked to the backward American style.

Comment: @Zhou There are too many reasons to mention why they do it this way.  I prefer it to any other language.  Using capital M versus lower case m to distinguish month from minute is error prone.  Plus, Go supports at least 4 ways to express month: 1-digit (only 2 if month is double digit), 2-digit (always 2-digits), 3-letter abbreviation (i.e. "Jan") and full month name (i.e. "January").  That's just scratching the surface.  There are many more reasons.  Trust me, it's better in Go than anywhere else around and no outside libraries needed.

Comment: @GoForth any languages out there have all 1-digit, 2-digit, short and long month formats and even more. There's no reason to use numbers like that. What does `2006` mean? June 20th, year 2006 or 20:06 o'clock? OK it's clear in this case, but how about `Z07002`, `-07002`? Non-prefix systems like this is broken. And the order is silly. The ISO 8601 format is much clearer

Comment: @phuclv "any languages out there have all 1-digit, 2-digit...".  No, they don't.  You can't even format dates in JavaScript without a library.  For example, in JavaScript I want you to give me a 3-letter abbreviated version of the month of the current time and I want you to do it in one line.  In Go it would just be `time.Now().Format("Jan")`.  In JavaScript, you would fumble around with regex to come close to that and it would be ugly.  How about if I asked for full month name then 2-digit year?  Again, in JavaScript it's clumsy.  In Go, it's just `time.Now().Format("Jan 06")`.  Go wins.

Comment: @GoForth JavaScript is just completely broken. Decent languages like C# and all OSes' locale formatting have that feature. In C# it's simply `DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM")`

Comment: So a programming language uses a non standard way to represent datetime. Wow, just wow. And I though JavaScript datetime sucks

Answer (score 44):

This question comes in top of Google search when you find "golang current time format" so, for all the people that want to use another format, remember that you can always call to:

```
t := time.Now()

t.Year()

t.Month()

t.Day()

t.Hour()

t.Minute()

t.Second()
```

For example, to get current date time as "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS" (for example 2019-01-22T12:40:55) you can use these methods with fmt.Sprintf:

```
t := time.Now()
formatted := fmt.Sprintf("%d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d",
        t.Year(), t.Month(), t.Day(),
        t.Hour(), t.Minute(), t.Second())
```

As always, remember that docs are the best source of learning: https://golang.org/pkg/time/

Comment: This approach doesn't work for 3-letter month representation. `t.Month()` would return `January` and there's no way to convert it to `Jan`. You still need to use `t.Format("Jan")` for this

Comment: `t.Month().String()[:3]` can be used for 3 letter month.

Answer (score 29):

### Option 1: Go standard library

```
t.Format("20060102150405")
```

| Unit | Golang Layout | Examples | Note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Year | 06 | 21, 81, 01 |  |
| Year | 2006 | 2021, 1981, 0001 |  |
| Month | January | January, February, December |  |
| Month | Jan | Jan, Feb, Dec |  |
| Month | 1 | 1, 2, 12 |  |
| Month | 01 | 01, 02, 12 |  |
| Day | Monday | Monday, Wednesday, Sunday |  |
| Day | Mon | Mon, Wed, Sun |  |
| Day | 2 | 1, 2, 11, 31 |  |
| Day | 02 | 01, 02, 11, 31 | zero padded day of the month |
| Day | _2 | ⎵1, ⎵2, 11, 31 | space padded day of the month |
| Day | 002 | 001, 002, 011, 031, 145, 365, 366 | zero padded day of the year |
| Day | __2 | ⎵⎵1, ⎵⎵2, ⎵11, ⎵31, 365, 366 | space padded day of the year |
| Part of day | PM | AM, PM |  |
| Part of day | pm | am, pm |  |
| Hour 24h | 15 | 00, 01, 12, 23 |  |
| Hour 12h | 3 | 1, 2, 12 |  |
| Hour 12h | 03 | 01, 02, 12 |  |
| Minute | 4 | 0, 4 ,10, 35 |  |
| Minute | 04 | 00, 04 ,10, 35 |  |
| Second | 5 | 0, 5, 25 |  |
| Second | 05 | 00, 05, 25 |  |
| 10<sup>-1</sup> to 10<sup>-9</sup> s | .0 .000000000 | .1, .199000000 | Trailing zeros included |
| 10<sup>-1</sup> to 10<sup>-9</sup> s | .9 .999999999 | .1, .199 | Trailing zeros omitted |
| Time zone | MST | UTC, MST, CET |  |
| Time zone | Z07 | Z, +08, -05 | Z is for UTC |
| Time zone | Z0700 | Z, +0800, -0500 | Z is for UTC |
| Time zone | Z070000 | Z, +080000, -050000 | Z is for UTC |
| Time zone | Z07:00 | Z, +08:00, -05:00 | Z is for UTC |
| Time zone | Z07:00:00 | Z, +08:00:00, -05:00:00 | Z is for UTC |
| Time zone | -07 | +00, +08, -05 |  |
| Time zone | -0700 | +0000, +0800, -0500 |  |
| Time zone | -070000 | +000000, +080000, -050000 |  |
| Time zone | -07:00 | +00:00, +08:00, -05:00 |  |
| Time zone | -07:00:00 | +00:00:00, +08:00:00, -05:00:00 |  |

In Golang 1.17+ for fraction of seconds (.999 or .000) you can use `,` instead of `.` (,999 or ,000) but output is always with `.`!!! See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/48037

### Option 2: strftime Go implementation

```
import strftime "github.com/itchyny/timefmt-go"
```

```
strftime.Format(t, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

See for more info

https://github.com/itchyny/timefmt-go

https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So there is no way to get a 24 hour value without 0 padding. Also, choosing 15 instead of 13 for the 24 hour padding is a weird choice.

Answer (score 14):

```
import("time")

layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"
str := "2014-11-12T11:45:26.371Z"
t, err := time.Parse(layout, str)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(t)
```

gives:

```
>> 2014-11-12 11:45:26.371 +0000 UTC
```

Comment: Thanks for your example, did something similar https://play.golang.org/p/POjXbG1hQWI

Answer (score 8):

Time package in Golang has some methods that might be worth looking.

> func (Time) Format
>
> func (t Time) Format(layout string) string
>   Format returns a textual representation of the time value formatted according to layout, which defines the format by showing how the reference time,
>
> Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
>   would be displayed if it were the value; it serves as an example of the desired output. The same display rules will then be applied to the time value. Predefined layouts ANSIC, UnixDate, RFC3339 and others describe standard and convenient representations of the reference time. For more information about the formats and the definition of the reference time, see the documentation for ANSIC and the other constants defined by this package.

Source (http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format)

I also found an example of defining the layout (http://golang.org/src/pkg/time/example_test.go)

```
func ExampleTime_Format() {
        // layout shows by example how the reference time should be represented.
        const layout = "Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04pm (MST)"
        t := time.Date(2009, time.November, 10, 15, 0, 0, 0, time.Local)
        fmt.Println(t.Format(layout))
        fmt.Println(t.UTC().Format(layout))
        // Output:
    // Nov 10, 2009 at 3:00pm (PST)
        // Nov 10, 2009 at 11:00pm (UTC)
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Go standard library: [time](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/5b9206f64ef4d8ea3201627cf9ba5c2b86e65022/src/time/format.go#L91-L154)

```golang
now := time.Now()
fmt.Println(now) // 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001
fmt.Println(now.Format("20060102150405"))
fmt.Println(now.Format("2006/01/02/15/04/05"))
fmt.Println(now.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
fmt.Println(now.Format("2006-01-02 15:04"))
fmt.Println(now.Format("2006/01/02 15:04:05"))
fmt.Println(now.Format("2006/01/02 15:04:05 (-0700)"))
fmt.Println(now.Format("2006年01月02日 15:04"))
fmt.Println(now.Format(time.Layout))   // 01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700
fmt.Println(now.Format(time.ANSIC))    // Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006
fmt.Println(now.Format(time.UnixDate)) // Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 MST 2006
fmt.Println(now.Format(time.RubyDate)) // Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 -0700 2006
fmt.Println(now.Format(time.RFC822))   // 02 Jan 06 15:04 MST
fmt.Println(now.Format(time.RFC850))   // Monday, 02-Jan-06 15:04:05 MST
fmt.Println(now.Format(time.Kitchen))  // 3:04PM
fmt.Println(now.Format(time.Stamp))    // Jan _2 15:04:05
```

<kbd>[Go playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/46h-KLK_BcM)</kbd>