# Convert time.Time to string

Tags: string, go, datetime, time

I'm trying to add some values from my database to a `[]string` in Go. Some of these are timestamps.

I get the error:

> cannot use U.Created_date (type time.Time) as type string in array element

Can I convert `time.Time` to `string`?

```
type UsersSession struct {
    Userid int
    Timestamp time.Time
    Created_date time.Time
}

type Users struct {
    Name string
    Email string
    Country string
    Created_date time.Time
    Id int
    Hash string
    IP string
}
```

```
var usersArray = [][]string{}

rows, err := db.Query("SELECT u.id, u.hash, u.name, u.email, u.country, u.IP, u.created_date, us.timestamp, us.created_date FROM usersSession AS us LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = us.userid WHERE us.timestamp + interval 30 minute >= now()")

U := Users{}
US := UsersSession{}

for rows.Next() {
    err = rows.Scan(&U.Id, &U.Hash, &U.Name, &U.Email, &U.Country, &U.IP, &U.Created_date, &US.Timestamp, &US.Created_date)
    checkErr(err)

    userid_string := strconv.Itoa(U.Id)
    user := []string{userid_string, U.Hash, U.Name, U.Email, U.Country, U.IP, U.Created_date, US.Timestamp, US.Created_date}
    // -------------
    // ^ this is where the error occurs
    // cannot use U.Created_date (type time.Time) as type string in array element (for US.Created_date and US.Timestamp aswell)
    // -------------

    usersArray = append(usersArray, user)
    log.Print("usersArray: ", usersArray)
}
```

Comment: It is worth highlighting the fact the compiler error describes the error completely. You cannot put a type Time in an array of a strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format current time using a yyyyMMddHHmmss format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234104/how-to-format-current-time-using-a-yyyymmddhhmmss-format)

Comment: I couldn't get some of the suggestions working, I used `time.Now().String()` for now

Answer (score 267, accepted):

You can use the [`Time.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.String) method to convert a [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) to a `string`. This uses the format string `"2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST"`.

If you need other custom format, you can use [`Time.Format()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format). For example to get the timestamp in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` use the format string `"2006-01-02 15:04:05"`.

Example:

```
t := time.Now()
fmt.Println(t.String())
fmt.Println(t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/VysF0Eu7v8)):

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
2009-11-10 23:00:00
```

Note: time on the Go Playground is always set to the value seen above. Run it locally to see current date/time.

Also note that using `Time.Format()`, as the layout `string` you always have to pass the same time –called the *reference* time– formatted in a way you want the result to be formatted. This is documented at `Time.Format()`:

> Format returns a textual representation of the time value formatted according to layout, which defines the format by showing how the reference time, defined to be
>
> ```
> Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
> ```
>
> would be displayed if it were the value; it serves as an example of the desired output. The same display rules will then be applied to the time value.

Comment: I wonder why `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006`, why not keep a simpler date or just `yyyy-mm.....`.

Comment: @P.... Because it contains the parts in numerical order: 1: Jan (1st month), 2: 2nd, 3: 15 (3pm), 4: 04, 5: 05, 6: 2006, 7: -7 (time zone).

Answer (score 32):

```
package main                                                                                                                                                           

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// @link https://golang.org/pkg/time/

func main() {

    //caution : format string is `2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000000`
    current := time.Now()

    fmt.Println("origin : ", current.String())
    // origin :  2016-09-02 15:53:07.159994437 +0800 CST

    fmt.Println("mm-dd-yyyy : ", current.Format("01-02-2006"))
    // mm-dd-yyyy :  09-02-2016

    fmt.Println("yyyy-mm-dd : ", current.Format("2006-01-02"))
    // yyyy-mm-dd :  2016-09-02

    // separated by .
    fmt.Println("yyyy.mm.dd : ", current.Format("2006.01.02"))
    // yyyy.mm.dd :  2016.09.02

    fmt.Println("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss : ", current.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
    // yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss :  2016-09-02 15:53:07

    // StampMicro
    fmt.Println("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss: ", current.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000"))
    // yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss:  2016-09-02 15:53:07.159994

    //StampNano
    fmt.Println("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss: ", current.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000000"))
    // yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss:  2016-09-02 15:53:07.159994437
}
```

Comment: When I try fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2017/20/01 13:53:35")) I am getting strange 21017/210/01 112:3012:1230

Comment: use fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006/01/02 15:04:05"))   , because the format string is fixed, It's "2006 01 02 15 04 05"

Answer (score 10):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    v , _ := time.Now().UTC().MarshalText()
    fmt.Println(string(v))
}
```

Output : `2009-11-10T23:00:00Z`

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xbQzszzVPjM)

Comment: To future generations who read this and are too lazy to consult the docs for the details (like me): the MarshalText() method returns a byte array aka byte slice and an error.

Answer (score 3):

Go Playground
http://play.golang.org/p/DN5Py5MxaB

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    // The Time type implements the Stringer interface -- it
    // has a String() method which gets called automatically by
    // functions like Printf().
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", t)

    // See the Constants section for more formats
    // http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format
    formatedTime := t.Format(time.RFC1123)
    fmt.Println(formatedTime)
}
```

Comment: When I try fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2017/20/01 13:53:35")) I am getting strange 21017/210/01 112:3012:1230

Comment: because you do 20 which is not meaningful for go so 2 is the date which was 21 probably at that time and the extra 0 is just appended @irom

Answer (score 3):

Please find the simple solution to convete Date & Time Format in Go Lang. Please find the example below.

Package Link: https://github.com/vigneshuvi/GoDateFormat.

Please find the plackholders:https://medium.com/@Martynas/formatting-date-and-time-in-golang-5816112bf098

```
package main


// Import Package
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "github.com/vigneshuvi/GoDateFormat"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Go Date Format(Today - 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'): ", GetToday(GoDateFormat.ConvertFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z")))
    fmt.Println("Go Date Format(Today - 'yyyy-MMM-dd'): ", GetToday(GoDateFormat.ConvertFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd")))
    fmt.Println("Go Time Format(NOW - 'HH:MM:SS'): ", GetToday(GoDateFormat.ConvertFormat("HH:MM:SS")))
    fmt.Println("Go Time Format(NOW - 'HH:MM:SS tt'): ", GetToday(GoDateFormat.ConvertFormat("HH:MM:SS tt")))
}

func GetToday(format string) (todayString string){
    today := time.Now()
    todayString = today.Format(format);
    return
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```golang
strconv.Itoa(int(time.Now().Unix()))
```