# How to convert time.Time object to formatted string using .Format in golang?

Tags: postgresql, go, interface, formatting

I'm currently attempting to fetch a time.Time object from my SQL database and convert the retrieved value to a formatted string that looks like so:

```
TIME_FORMAT := "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
```

This is the format I have used to do the same thing in Python, but I know it is not correct for go. I have already grabbed the value from the DB, and now just need to format it. Please note I have defined ccc.Ia_date as interface{} type because it is possible that this value in the DB could be null. Here is a clip of my code:

```
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(ccc.Ia_date))  //gives me time.Time
t := ccc.Ia_date //which prints as: 2016-11-16 21:06:39 +0000 +0000
fmt.Println(t.Format())
```

and I get the following error:

t.Format undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)

Am I missing an import? Or is this just not possible using interface types? If so, what alternatives do I have to accept null values from the DB?
(I have already seen the related answer to [Golang: convert time.Time to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119748/golang-convert-time-time-to-string) - I tried that solution but I'm not grabbing time.Now and that's the only difference I see)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `interface{}` value holding a [`time.time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) value, you may use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to obtain the wrapped `time.Time`:

```
if t, ok := ccc.Ia_date.(time.Time); ok {
    // here t is of type time.Time, and so you can call its Format() method:
    fmt.Println(t.Format(layout))
} else {
    // ccc.Ia_date is not of type time.Time, or it is nil
}
```

Note that it would be easier to just use a pointer `*time.Time` if you want to allow `nil`, and so you don't need to use type assertion. See this answer for more details: [Golang JSON omitempty With time.Time Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643815/golang-json-omitempty-with-time-time-field/32646035#32646035)

If `ccc.Ia_date` would be of type `*time.Time`:

```
if ccc.Ia_date != nil {
    fmt.Println(ccc.Ia_date.Format(layout))
}
```

And the layout string for your desired format is:

```
layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05"
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The problem is that if I define Ia_date within a struct ( which I do --> ccc.Ia_date) as *time.Time, I cannot assign the newly converted string back to that value as it will only accept objects of type *time.Time
So I will try your interface solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues.  First off, if `ccc.Ia_date` is an `interface{}`, you must type-assert it to a `time.Time` before you can use any methods of a `time.Time`.  You can do this using the two-argument type-assertion form to avoid panics:

```
t, ok := ccc.Ia_date.(time.Time)
if !ok {
    // wrong type or nil value, handle it
}
t.Format(timeFormat)
```

You also need to define your format string.  The format string is defined as a standardized date and time, that being `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006`.  So for your format, you want:

```
time_format := "2006-01-02T15:04:05"
t.Format(timeFormat)
```

However, this lacks a timezone.  It is also nearly identical to RFC3339 (`"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"`), which you can use instead:

```
t.Format(time.RFC3339)
```