# How to format todays date in go as dd-mm-yyyy?

Tags: go

I am trying to format todays date in golang and seem to be struggling with something i deem to be quite simple.

I am trying to get todays date in the format of dd-mm-yyy

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: In which database n also u can simply get the result by google

Comment: i did not mention anything to do with databases @Rams? i will check that answer @NaveenKumarNamachivayam

Comment: best answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39287194/2152652

Comment: I disagree that this is duplicated question. Provided answers show American date formats, which have nothing to do with the formats used in most European countries.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It works this way in Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/kBjTxZS9Y7

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("02-01-2006"))
}
```