# Easy way to receive a string from day from time.Now()

Tags: go

I'm trying to get the day as a string from a time.Now() instance.

```
now := time.Now() // .String() would give me the entire date as a string which I don't need
day := now.Day()) // is what I want but as a String.
```

So string(day) tells me "can not convert day to string".

For me now.Day().String() would be nice but there is no such method...

I could now try to take time.Now().String() and manipulate until the day is left over. But there should be a easier way to do it...

Comment: What is "day"? Day of week? Day of the month? Day in the year?

Comment: day as the day of the month. thx for asking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert time.Time to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119748/convert-time-time-to-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strconv` to convert `int` to `string`

```
strconv.Itoa(day)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can import and use `strconv` as KibGzr mentioned. Just to give a complete example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now() 
    day := now.Day()
    fmt.Printf("%T\n",(day))
    fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(day))
    dayString := strconv.Itoa(day)
    fmt.Printf("%T",(dayString))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Mqs24FJhCoi