# Logrus timestamp formatting

Tags: logging, go

I'm trying to transition from the Golang log package to [Logrus](https://github.com/Sirupsen/logrus).  My issue is around how to customize the timestamp format of logged messages.  The default is a counter of seconds since start but I want a "2016-03-24 17:10:15" format.  My simple test code is:

```
package main

import (
        "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
        customFormatter := new(logrus.TextFormatter)
        customFormatter.TimestampFormat = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
        logrus.SetFormatter(customFormatter)
        logrus.Info("Hello Walrus")
}
```

This compiles and runs fine but the timestamp format is unchanged. Can anyone offer some insight into why it isn't working?

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I believe you want to set the following field to true to enable the timestamp when running it yourself with a TTY attached.

From the [`logrus.TextFormatter`](https://godoc.org/github.com/Sirupsen/logrus#TextFormatter) documentation:

```
// Enable logging the full timestamp when a TTY is attached instead of just
// the time passed since beginning of execution.
FullTimestamp bool
```

Tweaking your provided example:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
    customFormatter := new(logrus.TextFormatter)
    customFormatter.TimestampFormat = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
    logrus.SetFormatter(customFormatter)
    logrus.Info("Hello Walrus before FullTimestamp=true")
    customFormatter.FullTimestamp = true
    logrus.Info("Hello Walrus after FullTimestamp=true")
}
```

Produces:

```
$ go run main.go
INFO[0000] Hello Walrus before FullTimestamp=true
INFO[2016-03-24 20:18:56] Hello Walrus after FullTimestamp=true
```

Comment: Why is that particular date used? Any other date in the same format results in strange results. The same date with 2007 gives me 3007 as the current year.

Comment: Golang's time formatting insanity is to use so called "reference date" as a template so instead of "YYYY-MM-DD" one have to use "2006-01-02" literally. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234104

Comment: As a one-liner: `logrus.SetFormatter(&logrus.TextFormatter{TimestampFormat: "2006-01-02 15:04:05", FullTimestamp: true})`

Comment: I want milisecond too, how can I do that ?

Comment: @insanely_sin `"2006-01-02 15:04:05.000"`