# How to parse datetime in golang in special format?

Tags: go, time

I has a special time string like this: `February 24, 2017 , 1:44 pm` and want to translate it to a golang time.Time object, does anyone know how to do this work. I have tried to using `time.Parse()`, but always got errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a link to a stack that shows you a list of formatters
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234104/how-to-format-current-time-using-a-yyyymmddhhmmss-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the format string `January 2, 2006 , 3:04 pm` to parse that kind of string.

Example:
https://play.golang.org/p/4HgRekLr-7

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Read https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants to know how to define your own formats or use predefined formates.