# GO Parsing Custom Time

Tags: go, time

Im trying to parse date with custom format- `ddmmmyyyy`. for example:

```
15may1997
dd 15 
mmm may 
yyyy 1997
```

This is my code:

```
const customFormat = "02jan2006"
t, err := time.Parse(customFormat, "15may1997")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

And this is the output:

```
parsing time "15may1997" as "02jan2006": cannot parse "may1997" as "jan"
```

The parsing succeed only when changing the day:

```
t, err := time.Parse(customFormat, "15jan2006")
```

I have tried to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234104/how-to-format-current-time-using-a-yyyymmddhhmmss-format) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106541/parsing-date-time-strings-which-are-not-standard-formats) and more articles, but couldn't figure out how to custom to my format.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: *"The recognized day of week formats are "Mon" and "Monday". The recognized month formats are "Jan" and "January"."* i.e. Use `Jan` instead of `jan`. https://play.golang.com/p/ndO8Vf1MkIQ

Comment: you are absolutely right :) thanks mkoprita

Answer (score 1):

Golang time.Parse parses a formatted string on the basis of layout and returns the time value it represents.The layout which defines the format is **Case-sensitive** and has fixed predefined values.

So you need to update customFormat = "02jan2006" to **"02Jan2006"**

Below is the list of Case-sensitive Placeholders for different parts of the datetime.

```
--------------- + ------------ +
Type            | Placeholder  |
--------------- + ------------ +
Year            | 2006         |
Year            | 06           | 
Month           | 01           |
Month           | 1            |
Month           | Jan          |
Month           | January      |
Day             | 02           |
Day             | 2            |
Week day        | Mon          |
Week day        | Monday       |
Hours           | 03           |
Hours           | 3            |
Hours           | 15           |
Minutes         | 04           |
Minutes         | 4            |
Seconds         | 05           | 
Seconds         | 5            |
AM or PM        | PM           | 
Miliseconds     | .000         |
Microseconds    | .000000      |
Nanoseconds     | .000000000   |
Timezone offset | -0700        |
Timezone offset | -07:00       |   
Timezone offset | Z0700        |  
Timezone offset | Z07:00       |   
Timezone        | MST          |
--------------- + ------------ +
```