# Get 12 hour from time in Go

Tags: go, time, format

Go noob here, and all I want to do is use the time format constants list https://golang.org/src/time/format.go that are mentioned in 3 posts here on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20234207 https://stackoverflow.com/a/14106561 https://stackoverflow.com/a/20234207). None of which including the docs (at least that I can tell) have an example of how to use them.

I would expect this to work (but it clearly does not):

```
t := time.Now()

log.Println(t.stdHour12())
```

Can you please tell me how to get only the hour (in 12 hour time) for a given time t (ex: 10 from 2021-03-09 22:45:04.009063861 -0500 EST)?

```
const (
    stdLongMonth      = "January"
    stdMonth          = "Jan"
    stdNumMonth       = "1"
    stdZeroMonth      = "01"
    stdLongWeekDay    = "Monday"
    stdWeekDay        = "Mon"
    stdDay            = "2"
    stdUnderDay       = "_2"
    stdZeroDay        = "02"
    stdHour           = "15"
    stdHour12         = "3"
    stdZeroHour12     = "03"
    stdMinute         = "4"
    stdZeroMinute     = "04"
    stdSecond         = "5"
    stdZeroSecond     = "05"
    stdLongYear       = "2006"
    stdYear           = "06"
    stdPM             = "PM"
    stdpm             = "pm"
    stdTZ             = "MST"
    stdISO8601TZ      = "Z0700"  // prints Z for UTC
    stdISO8601ColonTZ = "Z07:00" // prints Z for UTC
    stdNumTZ          = "-0700"  // always numeric
    stdNumShortTZ     = "-07"    // always numeric
    stdNumColonTZ     = "-07:00" // always numeric
)
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: From the answers received so far, I see that I cannot use the constants above to achieve what I want so I changed the wording of this question to specifically ask to return the hour (and just the hour) for a given time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Time` object specifies the full date and time. You can extract just the time, if you like:

```
func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t.Format(time.Kitchen))
}
```

`time.Kitchen` is defined in the `time` package as `Kitchen = "3:04PM"`

If you want to understand how the format is interpreted, read [this piece of documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants) carefully

---

If you just need the hour, call the `Hour()` method on a `Time` object. If you want it in 12-hour format, you can just do modulo 12:

```
func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t.Hour())
    fmt.Println(t.Hour() % 12)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit? Why `(time.Kitchen)`? Also, I just tested it in the go playground and it yields `11:00PM` (note that it is 10:39PM).

Comment: @paulguy: added details. Note that the playground is a sandboxed environment and not a "real" machine. Try running the code locally on your computer, you should get the right time.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it on my computer and you are correct. I have edited the question to be more specific to my goal of getting only the hour (in 12 hour time). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @paulguy: I've updated my answer based on your edit and question in the comment

Answer (score 1):

These are constants representing tokens used internally by formatting code in `time` package (note they start with lower letter so they aren't exported and you can't even use them outside `time` package).

If you want to come up with your own format in Go (for both parsing and output) you simply define it using these tokens "as example" and `Format()` will parse it and apply that format (if valid) to itself.

```golang
const (
    MyLayout = "3"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t.Format(MyLayout))
}
```

Available tokens are listed for example [here](https://yourbasic.org/golang/format-parse-string-time-date-example/#layout-options).

Comment: I guess it still doesn't make sense to me how to use this to only return the current hour. From what you've shown (and looking at the constants from the docs) I would "come up with" something like `const (StdHour12 = "3")` but that doesn't work as expected (yields 6 when it is currently 10). Also, your `MyLayout` did not return the correct time (yields Tue 10:11PM when it is currently Tue 10:24PM).

Comment: Sorry, I meant to also say that regarding your "Available tokens are listed for example...", I looked at it and I don't see how to use say: `Hours 03   3   15` to get just the hour in 12 hour time.

Comment: Thats probably because you tried it in Playground which is sandbox and reports incorrect time. To get just hour from time you can use `t.Hours() % 12` which doesn't require any parsing and formatting.