# Calculate the Closest Time Difference in HH:MM(am/pm) Format using Go

Tags: go

I got a bit problem when calculating the time difference from PM to AM or vice versa. For instance:

```golang
ref, _ := time.Parse("03:04pm", "11:59pm")
t, _ := time.Parse("03:04am", "12:00am")

fmt.Println(t.Sub(ref).Minutes()) // Got -719, my expectation is 1 (minutes)
```

Actually that's true, but I want to get the smallest difference.

Comment: `time.Time` represents a full date and time. You're comparing two times on the same day. What you want is `12:00am` from the next day but you're not specifying a day at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you got -719 is that you do not provide date information and in second time.Parse you have typo in template. Template has to contain `pm`

```
time.Parse("03:04pm", "11:59pm") // 0000-01-01 23:59:00 +0000 UTC
time.Parse("03:04am", "12:00am") // 0000-01-01 12:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

You need to provide day information and pm in template

```
time.Parse("02 03:04pm", "01 11:59pm") // 0000-01-01 23:59:00 +0000 UTC
time.Parse("02 03:04pm", "02 12:00am") // 0000-01-02 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69338568/12301864