# How to parse time with unique format in golang?

Tags: go

I have date time with format 18/09/21 14.56 from excel. I want to parse and  format to different format `2006-01-02 hh:mm:ss`

Is possible to parse time with format 18/09/21 14.56 in golang and then format it to eg. `2006-01-02 hh:mm:ss`

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format current time using a yyyyMMddHHmmss format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234104/how-to-format-current-time-using-a-yyyymmddhhmmss-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Golang use example based template for `Parse` and `Format`.

```
01   -> month with zero prefix
02   -> day with zero prefix
06   -> year (last two digits)
15   -> hour (24h based)
04   -> minutes with zero prefix
05   -> seconds with zero prefix
2006 -> long year
```

```
t, _ := time.Parse("02/01/06 15.04", "18/09/21 14.56")

t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05") // 2021-09-18 14:56:00
```

For more layout options see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69338568/12301864

Answer (score 0):

```golang
func TestTime(t *testing.T) {
    tm, err := time.Parse("06/01/02 15.04", "18/09/21 14.56")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    log.Println(tm.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.